# Function not returning value when using axios

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, axios, graphql

I am doing a simple post method using `axios` inside a function that I want to call later. But my function is not returning anything.

My function:

```
const myFunc = (query) => {
    let arr = [];
    axios({
        url: GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
        method: 'post',
        headers: headers,
        data: { query: query}
    }).then((response) => {
        response.data.forEach(d => {
            arr.push(qs.parse(d.node.name));
        });
    });
    return arr;
} 

myFunc(myQuery); //not returning anything
```

My function is returning nothing. How do I get the array back from the function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `await` for the result of your `myFunc`:

```js
const myFunc = (query) => {
  let arr = [];
  return axios({
    url: GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
    method: 'post',
    headers: headers,
    data: { query: query }
  }).then((response) => {
    response.data.forEach((d) => {
      arr.push(qs.parse(d.node.name));
    });
    return arr;
  });
};

await myFunc(myQuery);
```

Comment: You would also want to make the `myFunc` function `async`.

Comment: Hi @Ankit, you don't have to make it `async` if it returns a Promise. The beauty of Promise is you can `await` them as long as you are in a `async` function / context

Comment: Thanks for the info, you can wrap the myFunc in the async function, so as not to confuse him.